# twitter bootstrap v3 view layout in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my ASP.Net MVC razor app (which uses twitter bootstrap 3), I have a view used to display vaules (details view) as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelNo)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Model.ModelNo
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNo)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Model.SerialNo
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DrawingNo)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Model.DrawingNo
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Model.Manufacturer
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MinorSubLocation)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Model.MinorSubLocation
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipmentTypeId)
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Model.EquipmentTypeName
    </div>
</div>
```

The layout works well EXCEPT when a value returned from the model is null. When that happens, the "form-group" div following it ends up on the same line. In the image below, the MinorSubLocation is null:

[image]

It pretty much messes of the layout after that. I am pulling my hair out trying to get this to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add class `row` to `<div class="form-group">`

```
<div class="form-group row">
```